# What happens to a bride whose groom goes insane or disappears between kiddushin and nissuin?

Tags: marriage

What happens to a bride whose groom goes insane or disappears after kiddushin but before nissuin? Is she considered agunah or permitted to remarry?

Comment: Why would this be different from if he disappeared after nissuin

Comment: @DoubleAA i think that the OP thinks that Kiddushin is a half marriage and therefore might be a different din

Comment: @mennyg I don't even know what a half marriage is, but it doesn't sound like kiddushin to me.

Comment: @DoubleAA neither do I, but obviously the OP thinks theres a possibility

Comment: @mennyg Why not let the OP tell us what he is thinking? Maybe he has some other idea in mind (something about tnai, or mekach taut, or whatever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kiddushin make this woman prohibited to all men except her husband, despite that there is no nisuyim. She cannot remarry if he is yet alive and did not give her a Get. Source: Mishna Kiddushin.

#### Mishna:

> נִקְנֵית בְּכֶסֶף
>
> She is bought with money.

#### Yikar Tosfot Yom Tov (in name of the Ran):

> לְבַעְלָהּ לְהַצְרִיכָהּ מִמֶּנּוּ גֵט. הָרַ"ן:‏
>
> She needs a Get.